# Finding maximum edges between given nodes

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, breadth-first-search

There is a (bidirected or two-way) graph. My task is to find maximum edges between two given nodes **6** and **9** as per below image. There are two paths between 6 and 9. I have to pick longest path **6-1-3-5-9**. But my code is written about to find shortest path between given nodes and it is giving me result **6-1-3-9**. So, How could i change in the code to find longest path.

[graph image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5Efk.jpg)

I am using code from this link [minimum-number-of-edges-between-two-vertices-of-a-graph](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/minimum-number-of-edges-between-two-vertices-of-a-graph/)

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.Vector;

class Test {
  // Method for finding minimum no. of edge
  // using BFS
  static int minEdgeBFS(Vector<Integer> edges[], int u, int v, int n) {
    // visited[n] for keeping track of visited
    // node in BFS
    Vector<Boolean> visited = new Vector<Boolean>(n);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      visited.addElement(false);
    }

    // Initialize distances as 0
    Vector<Integer> distance = new Vector<Integer>(n);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      distance.addElement(0);
    }

    // queue to do BFS.
    Queue<Integer> Q = new LinkedList<>();
    distance.setElementAt(0, u);

    Q.add(u);
    visited.setElementAt(true, u);
    while (!Q.isEmpty()) {
      int x = Q.peek();
      Q.poll();

      for (int i = 0; i < edges[x].size(); i++) {
        if (visited.elementAt(edges[x].get(i))) continue;

        // update distance for i
        distance.setElementAt(distance.get(x) + 1, edges[x].get(i));
        Q.add(edges[x].get(i));
        visited.setElementAt(true, edges[x].get(i));
      }
    }
    return distance.get(v);
  }

  // method for addition of edge
  static void addEdge(Vector<Integer> edges[], int u, int v) {
    edges[u].add(v);
    edges[v].add(u);
  }

  // Driver method
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    // To store adjacency list of graph
    int n = 11;
    Vector<Integer> edges[] = new Vector[11];

    for (int i = 0; i < edges.length; i++) {
      edges[i] = new Vector<>();
    }

    addEdge(edges, 0, 1);
    addEdge(edges, 1, 2);
    addEdge(edges, 1, 7);
    addEdge(edges, 1, 6);
    addEdge(edges, 2, 8);
    addEdge(edges, 3, 1);
    addEdge(edges, 3, 4);
    addEdge(edges, 3, 9);
    addEdge(edges, 5, 3);
    addEdge(edges, 5, 9);
    addEdge(edges, 8, 10);
    int u = 6;
    int v = 9;
    System.out.println(minEdgeBFS(edges, u, v, n));
  }
}
```

Comment: Finding the shortest path and finding the longest path are totally different problems. So transforming the one in the other is not done by a small modification.

Comment: Can you be sure that the graph has no cycles? Otherwise the longest path could be infinite.

Comment: yes there is no cycle

Answer (score 1):

*"My task is to find maximum edges between two given nodes"*

That problem is [NP-hard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem) then, basically, check all possible paths is your best known algorithm.

But, you must define if one node can be used many times or only once. Then, using backtracking, use a `Set<Node or Edge>` to know when an edge (if a node can be visited many times) or node (if not) has been visited.

At the same time as that `Set`, keep the maximum value in the backtracking (only when you reach the destination node) to know the answer.

The next code compute the hamiltonian from two points in a bidirectional edges graph

```
package com.computermind.sandbox.algorithms;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

public class Hamilton {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        Graph g = new Graph();
        g.addEdge(6, 1);
        g.addEdge(7, 1);
        g.addEdge(2, 1);
        g.addEdge(3, 1);
        g.addEdge(2, 8);
        g.addEdge(8, 10);
        g.addEdge(3, 4);
        g.addEdge(3, 5);
        g.addEdge(3, 9);
        g.addEdge(9, 5);
        System.out.println(g.hamiltonian(6, 9));
    }

    static class Graph {
        private Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> edges = new HashMap<>();

        private void _addEdge(int a, int b) {
            if (!edges.containsKey(a))
                edges.put(a, new HashSet<>());
            edges.get(a).add(b);
        }

        public void addEdge(int a, int b) {
            _addEdge(a, b);
            _addEdge(b, a);
        }

        // assume nodes could be used many times, edges only once
        public List<Integer> hamiltonian(int a, int b) {
            List<Integer> solution = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int z : edges.get(a))
                hamiltonian(b, new Edge(a, z), new HashSet<>(), new ArrayList<>(), solution);
            solution.add(0, b);
            return solution;
        }

        // recursion with backtracking
        private void hamiltonian(int b, Edge edge, Set<Edge> visited, List<Integer> path, List<Integer> best) {
            // if this edge is not visited, visit
            if (!visited.contains(edge)) {
                // has been visited
                visited.add(edge);
                // add the source node
                path.add(0, edge.a);
                // if destination node is the final node check solution
                if (edge.b == b) {
                    // if you need all longest paths you could accumulate
                    if (path.size() > best.size()) {
                        best.clear();
                        best.addAll(path);
                    }
                }
                // even if it is the final node you must go forward since it could be a cross node
                for (int z : edges.get(edge.b))
                    hamiltonian(b, new Edge(edge.b, z), visited, path, best);
                // backtracking
                path.remove(0);
                visited.remove(edge);
            }
        }

        // WARN bidirectional edges
        static class Edge {
            int a; // from
            int b; // to

            public Edge(int a, int b) {
                this.a = a;
                this.b = b;
            }

            // max/min should be considered to be a->b equals than b->a
            @Override
            public int hashCode() {
                return 7 * Math.min(a, b) + Math.max(a, b);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean equals(Object obj) {
                if (!(obj instanceof Edge))
                    return false;
                Edge o = (Edge) obj;
                return Math.min(a, b) == Math.min(o.a, o.b) && Math.max(a, b) == Math.max(o.a, o.b);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

with output

[9, 5, 3, 1, 6]